# Using jQuery Validation, How do modify what is validated based on what is selected in a drop-down

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Using jQuery Validation, how do you modify what form elements get validated based on what a user selects in a drop-down element of the same form.

For example if a user selects a special type of credit card then the Card Verification # is no longer a required field.

Comment: Post some code for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `required` property to a function. Check the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation), but for example:

```
field: 
  required: function() {
    return $("[name=credit_card]").val() == "VISA";
  },
```